# Regex throws exception index out of range for unicode char?

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I have a regex that basically keeps all green text above a certain pattern (saves group1).

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/mK0jC3)

That's all working!

Now, if there is unicode chars when parsing per java. the m.find() below throws an exception index out of range -2.  The two chars in question are:

> text[23]55357
>   text[24]56561

looks like this below: [**Text String Value**](http://puu.sh/7L4BK.png)

```
String text = "Hi\n\nyo keep this here\n\nUnicode b4 here\n\nyo\ncut me:\n\nThis should be deleted";
System.out.println(text);
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(.+?)\\byo\\b(?:(?!cut me:|yo).)*cut me:",  Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
    text = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

So, my ask is why is this throwing?

I have tried using javaescape (apache utils) on the string and it prevents throwing but my regex find doesn't match if I do escape it.

Of course if you remove the unicode chars it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use like this.

As *This Should be deleted* in your string **should really mean** that

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(.+?)\\nyo\\n(?:(?!cut me:|yo).)*cut me:",  Pattern.DOTALL);
```

> Why it is throwing Exception?

**StringIndexOutOfBound Exception**(According To Oracle Documentation)

> Thrown by String methods to indicate that an index is either negative
>   or greater than the size of the string.

Here in your case it is thrown when you use `m.find()` as it tries to attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

As seems when you try with `\b`

```
System.out.println(m.groupCount());
```

this will return 0.

Comment: it looks like it prevents the error but I also need it to match patterns such as this -> http://regex101.com/r/vO1gC4